# $rootScope.$on in a service or factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem with the `$rootScope.$on` method in a service or Factory.

I have a service :

```
app.service('testService', function($rootScope){

this.var1 = 5;

this.change = function(n){
    this.var1 = n;
}

$rootScope.$on('service', function(event, n){
    //this.var1 = n;
    console.log(this.var1);

});
});
```

the Problem is that should print `5` in the console. but I can't access to the services's variables in the `$rootScope.$on` method ...

her is the controller :

```
app.controller( 'HelloCtrl', function($scope, testService, testFactory, $rootScope)
{
$scope.fromService = testService;

$rootScope.$broadcast("service", 12);
});
```

that's the JSFiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noteStylet/mc4ow2b6/3/)

What's the problem ?

What should I do ?

Comment: I wouldn't inject $rootScope or $scope into a factory. I usually only listen to events in my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `this` in another variable to make closure.

Inside callback `this` is another...

Hope it will help you:

```js
//angular.js example for factory vs service
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
app.service('testService', function($rootScope){

    var testService = this;
    
    this.var1 = 5;
    
    this.change = function(n){
        this.var1 = n;
    }
    
    $rootScope.$on('service', function(event, n){
        //this.var1 = n;
        console.log(testService.var1);
       
    });
});

app.controller( 'HelloCtrl', function($scope, testService, $rootScope)
{
    $scope.fromService = testService;

    $rootScope.$broadcast("service", 12);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mc4ow2b6/4/

Comment: But the JsFiddel has an invalid url .